# How to pass the object value in hashmap? I was referring to the details.getString("jobcategory") to send the value inside the hashmap key jobscategory

Tags: android, android-volley

```
  How to pass the object value in hashmap? I was referring to the details.getString("jobcategory") to send the value inside the hashmap key jobscategory> I'm using Android Volley. Thank you

   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response1);


                final JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("Jobs");


                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jobs = array.getJSONObject(i);

       
                    String companyDetails = jobs.getString("jobdetails");
                    JSONObject details = new JSONObject(companyDetails);
                    jobcat = details.getString("jobcategory");
```

I need to pass the value of jobcat = details.getString("jobcategory") which I know is 16 to Hashmap;

```
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("barangayid", preferences.getString("sessionBrgyID", null));
            data.put("jobcategory", jobcat);
            data.put("function", "get_user_jobs_by_category");
            System.out.println(data);
            return data;
```

but I get an error a null value.

Comment: Adding a little bit description and explanation might clear the confussion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `getParams` in the volley's request.

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("barangayid", preferences.getString("sessionBrgyID", null));
    data.put("jobcategory", jobcat);
    data.put("function", "get_user_jobs_by_category");
    System.out.println(data);
    return data;
}
```